# Stanford CoreNLP Server proxy issues

Tags: python, linux, proxy, stanford-nlp, ubuntu-16.04

I am running a [Stanford Core NLP server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) on a remote linux machine. This machine has a `http_proxy` set in my `.bashrc` profile to connect to the Internet. I would like to access the Core NLP server via a Python program using `requests` from the same machine.

If I set the `proxies` variable in the program using a GET or POST method, I get a `requests.exceptions.ProxyError`.

If I do not set the variable, I get a  `Cannot Connect. The proxy could not connect to the destination in time.` in the output from Stanford Core NLP Server.

The Stanford Core NLP server runs on Port `9000` while the HTTP proxy is set on `8080` in the bashrc profile file. Is there something I am missing?

Details of my Linux Machine

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: I'm not the person to help with setting up the proxy, but you can change the port that the server runs on by setting the `-port` command line argument to the server. Perhaps it has to be running on 8080?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried it too and yet I run into the same proxy issue unfortunately.